# Timed triggers for Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

In my project, I have a SQL table which keeps track of logged users. If a user is logged in, a flag field is set to `true` and if the user logs out the same flag is set to `false`.

The application (C#) is responsible to set the flag on or off and everything works fine when the user logs in and logs out before closing the application.

However, when a user is logged in and in case of a power outage for example —assuming power went off on the client side, but not on the server side— the users connection will drop before the application sets the `logged` flag to `false`. For compensation of this uncertainty case, I want the SQL server to check periodically (say, once every 5 minute), whether  the client is still there/logged/active or not.

How do I create a trigger for this case on the server side?

Comment: I think that you may want to re-think the working logic of your code.. I would suggest that if the user is logged in ..and there is a new session but they did not log in, then I would utilize some other mechanism of combined checks.. don't just rely on a single form of validation / verification.. is this a winforms or web forms project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to simply have a `last-contact-time` in the database and have the client inform the server every 4.5 minutes that the client is still "logged in".

To get 'logged in users' just select where `now` is less than `last-contact-time` plus 5 minutes.